# NodeJS route order

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I'm trying to understand how the route order works in nodeJS.

I have just one route in my app.js:

```
const formsCreatorRoute = require('./routes/formsCreator');
app.use('/formsCreator', formsCreatorRoute);
```

Then, in my formsCreator.js route folder I set two routes:

```
const express =  require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const formsCreatorController = require('../controllers/formsCreator');

router.get('/:pID/:uID', formsCreatorController.load);
router.get('/getForm/:fID/:pID', formsCreatorController.getFormByID);

module.exports = router;
```

The controller just export two test functions: load and getFormByID.

However, when I run http://localhost:3000/formsCreator/9/215 it should go to the load method in controller (first route), but it goes to the getFormByID. Why is it happen? Will it always run the last route?

Thanks

Comment: I've just copied & pasted your code and visiting `/formsCreator/9/215` executes function assigned to `/:pID/:uID` route.

Comment: If I debug the code, it calls the function getFormByID